# nginx is installed but site does not load

Tags: linux, nginx

I installed LEMP with [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-6) I have done all it says but when I enter my server ip address in my browser it takes some time to load the page and it seems like my browser is doing some processes to load the page but at last the page is blank.
I'v checked all the installation again and they were all installed.
I'v installed apache at the past and I know for apache server if you enter server ip address it shows " apache is functioning " but It's my first time installing nginx ; I want to install DirectAdmin and I don't know nginx is installed or not.
If anyone is familiar with nginx and can help me, I'll be apreciate that.

Update: When I use `service nginx status` it shows nginx is running.
Update: Flowing are the results of my checkings: 
Results of `netstat -tulpn | grep :80` :
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*` 
                 `LIST                                                 EN      10302/nginx`

Results of `ps aux | grep nginx` :

```
    nginx     8556  0.0  0.0 222416  3552 ?        S    09:04   0:00 php-fpm: pool w                                                 ww
nginx     8557  0.0  0.0 222416  3552 ?        S    09:04   0:00 php-fpm: pool w                                                 ww
nginx     8558  0.0  0.0 222416  3552 ?        S    09:04   0:00 php-fpm: pool w                                                 ww
nginx     8559  0.0  0.0 222416  3552 ?        S    09:04   0:00 php-fpm: pool w                                                 ww
nginx     8560  0.0  0.0 222416  3552 ?        S    09:04   0:00 php-fpm: pool w                                                 ww
root     10302  0.0  0.0  96032  1980 ?        Ss   09:11   0:00 nginx: master p                                                 rocess /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
nginx    10304  0.0  0.0  96436  2692 ?        S    09:11   0:00 nginx: worker p                                                 rocess
nginx    10305  0.0  0.0  96436  2692 ?        S    09:11   0:00 nginx: worker p                                                 rocess
nginx    10306  0.0  0.0  96436  2660 ?        S    09:11   0:00 nginx: worker p                                                 rocess
nginx    10307  0.0  0.0  96436  2672 ?        S    09:11   0:00 nginx: worker p                                                 rocess
root     12564  0.0  0.0 103312   856 pts/0    S+   09:59   0:00 grep nginx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIIIIINNNNNNAAAAAALLLLLLLY I Found the problem!
The problem was with my firewall.
If anyone else has the same problem it may be the firewall settings problem like mine So Do the flowing to fix this:

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

in the opened file find this line :

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Check that `--dport 80` is set to the port that you entered in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` if its something else like `--dport 22` change it to your default port.

---

Update:
After you changed the port you should run this code:

```
service iptables restart
```

And this is the page shows nginx is running :
[image]